# What are web services in asp.net and how can we use them

Tags: asp.net

I am new to asp.net and just started my first project. I heard about web services in asp.net. Can anyone tell me about how can they benefit me in my websites and applications and can it be run on window applications as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended way to write web services in .NET is using the [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119.aspx) (WCF). There are many tutorials online that will get you started. Here's [one on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) has given you the correct answer. I'll just add that this is a perfect example of the fact that you *must* be careful about things you read about, or find in Internet searches. There's plenty of bad information along with the good information - plenty of old information along with the current information.

You can find a lot of great information on ASMX web services (sometimes known as "ASP.NET Web Services"), and almost none of that information will tell you that you should not use ASMX web services.  Most of that information was written when ASMX web services were the *current* web service technology, so it will naturally not tell you that it stopped being current three  years ago.